# Android `MediaStore` diacritic characters parsing issue

Tags: android, audio, metadata, mediastore

I'm experiencing strange issue with android `MediaStore` (I use android 13, LineageOS 20.0 distribution). I have my music library stored on computer in `flac` format and properly tagged fields `artist`, `title`, `album` and so on (`mpd` parses and displays all tags correctly). Before I copy it to my android device I first convert all files to `opus` format and copy all tags from corresponding `flac` files using this script (for single file `$f`):

```bash
f="$1"
fout="${1%.*}.opus"

TITLE=$(metaflac "$f" --no-utf8-convert --show-tag=TITLE | cut -d '=' -f 2-)
ARTIST=$(metaflac "$f" --no-utf8-convert --show-tag=ARTIST | cut -d '=' -f 2-)
ALBUM=$(metaflac "$f" --no-utf8-convert --show-tag=ALBUM | cut -d '=' -f 2-)
DATE=$(metaflac  "$f" --no-utf8-convert --show-tag=DATE | cut -d '=' -f 2-)
GENRE=$(metaflac "$f" --no-utf8-convert --show-tag=GENRE | cut -d '=' -f 2-)
TRACKNUMBER=$(metaflac "$f" --no-utf8-convert --show-tag=TRACKNUMBER | cut -d '=' -f 2-)
TRACKTOTAL=$(metaflac "$f" --no-utf8-convert --show-tag=TRACKTOTAL | cut -d '=' -f 2-)

# Field "DATE" doesn't work on android, so have to use "YEAR" for compatibility

opusenc\
    --music\
    --bitrate 192\
    --discard-comments\
    --discard-pictures\
    --title "$TITLE"\
    --artist "$ARTIST"\
    --album "$ALBUM"\
    --date "$DATE"\
    --comment "YEAR=$DATE"\
    --genre "$GENRE"\
    --comment "TRACKNUMBER=$TRACKNUMBER"\
    --comment "TRACKTOTAL=$TRACKTOTAL"\
    "$f" "$fout"
```

After refreshing `MediaStore` all files (more than 2000) have their tags displayed properly (recognized `artist`, `genre`, grouped in `albums` with proper `year` and each file has good `title` and `tracknumber`/`tracktotal` in music player and also when exploring media in `Audio` section of `Files` app on android device), except of two with following tags (extracted using `opustags` program):

```
ENCODER=opusenc from opus-tools 0.2
title=Śmiech czy łzy
artist=Dżem
album=Detox
date=1991
YEAR=1991
genre=Polish Blues Rock
TRACKNUMBER=01
TRACKTOTAL=09
ENCODER_OPTIONS=--music --bitrate 192 --discard-comments --discard-pictures
```

```
ENCODER=opusenc from opus-tools 0.2
title=Do kołyski
album=2004
date=2004
YEAR=2004
genre=Polish Blues Rock
TRACKNUMBER=07
TRACKTOTAL=12
ENCODER_OPTIONS=--music --bitrate 192 --discard-comments --discard-pictures
```

for which `artist` is displayed as "`DĹĽem`" and `title` as "`Ĺšmiech czy Ĺ,zy`" and "`Do koĹ,yski`" respectively. The strange thing is that any other track by this artist (in particular from these two albums) are displayed properly (`artist` is "`Dżem`" and `title`s which contain diacritic characters are also good).

Let's focus on tags `artist=Dżem`, `title=Śmiech czy łzy`. What is even more strange, when I change them to `title=Smiech czy łzy` or `title=aaaaaaŚmiech czy łzy` for example, leaving `artist` unchanged, everything seems to work and this track is grouped with other tracks by "`Dżem`", not "`DĹĽem`" and music player displays diacritic characters in title properly.

I've tried:

- manually reset value of these tags
- using script above without `--no-utf8-convert` and changed system locale
- copy `flac` versions of these files to android device
- convert files to `mp3`, set tags using `id3v2` tool / format and then copy to android.

but nothing helped. I also suppose that my tags are all set correctly, because `mpd` does not have this issue regardless of the audio format (`flac`, `opus`, `mp3`) or metadata format (`vorbis comment`, `id3v2`).

Does anyone have idea what's going on and how can I fix it? In particular why any other file with `artist`, `title` or `album` containing diacritic characters is parsed correctly by `MediaStore`?